# Full H-bridge unwanted surge in output square wave

Tags: mosfet-driver, h-bridge, square

I'm designing a H-bridge driven by two IR2110 mosfet drivers and using four NMOS (IRFS SL7440) transistors. Below a picture of my schematic. I am using 98uF bootstrap capacitors, and apply two complementary 50 kHz pulses to the HIN and LIN inputs of the two mosfet drivers. This gives me a 50 kHz output block signal. Below are pictures of the HO1, LO1 outputs of the left mosfet driver. I can't seem to identify where the voltage spike at the rising edge of the HO block wave comes from. This results in a same voltage spike at the load v+ (the load is a 30 uH inductance). The NMOS transistors already have flyback diodes internally.

[image]

Could someone clarify what could be (a solution to) the issue? Because for my application I need a rather perfect output block signal before letting the coil make it sinusoidal.

Comment: Doesn't 98 uF seem about 100 times too large?

Comment: How so? Do you have a good reference for choosing bootstrap capacitors?

Comment: I have experience.

Comment: The bootstrap capacitor is clearly over valued and 98 µF can't work. Remember it is charged abruptly when the low-side switch conducts so think of the poor 4148 seeing all the current. Replace it by a 100-nF value and it should work better. In a real application, replace the 4148 by a MUR160 or equivalent.

Comment: Please [read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics?r=Saves_AllUserSaves).